# Selectively showing groups in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report which displays information by group; I'd like to not show any group that doesn't have at least two items in it. Is there an easy way to do this?

Example:

```
Bob
   3/1
   4/3

Joe
   3/2
   3/7
   3/9

Mark
  5/9

James

John
  8/17
  9/2
```

Grouped on name, should not show Mark or James.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your report is simplistic enough, you can get away with just suppressing the Group Header, Group Footer, and Details sections by using a summary function like `count({table.somedate},{table.dudesname}) < 2`. Note that the second parameter to a summary function has to be a *field being used to group on*.

Your mileage may vary with doing it this way. If you are displaying calculated summaries in the report footer, for example, it won't make sense to just suppress these groups as their data will still affect any report-level summary. The other problem you might run into is needing to use a *distinct count* on some field instead of just a *count*, depending on your table joins.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a group-selection formula (Report | Selection Formula | Group...):

```
Count({table.field_to_count}, {table.grouped_field}) < 2
```